# Visual Studio 2017 15.5 creating all files as Administrator and Read Only

Tags: visual-studio

**Newly posed question (see below for original question)**

How can I prevent Visual Studio from creating all project files and app generated files as owned by Administrator and Read Only (even when running VS as a non administrative user)?

Any projects I create are owned by “Administrators”, and have “Read-only” permissions on all files and directories.  Because this is a corporate owned machine and because I run as a non administrative user, this leaves me unable to modify these files outside of Visual Studio.  :(

**Possibly related:**

I found this Microsoft Article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj662724.aspx) which says if Visual Studio is run as administrator, it will have “(Administrator)” in the titlebar of the application.  Sure enough, it has that is what I see, although Task Manager clearly shows my ID (a non administrator) as the “User Name”, so this is very misleading.

**Also:**

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167288/vs-2017-always-opening-as-administrator.html

I tried the same shortcut method they suggest (which tries to “RUNASINVOKER”, but VS still has “(Administrator)” in the title bar)

**==Below is how I was originally asking for help, for historical reference==**

How do I prevent this from happening?  I would expect them to be owned by the user running the code.

Code snippet:

Repository.Clone(“https://github.company.com/org/repo”,@“C:\some\path\to\repo”, co);

**Background:**

This clones the repo, which is great, but the resultant files are marked as owned by Administrator and are Read Only, so I have no way to delete or modify them after the clone is done (this is a corporate owned computer on which I have no admin rights).

Further info:

Note that I’ve confirmed with Task Manager that both Visual Studio itself (which is where I’m writing/testing this code) as well as the resulting “dotnet.exe” window both run as a NON administrator user ID.

Comment: I think your question(s) are implied, but I think it'd be better if you explicitly state them in the future.

Comment: I agree with you - it got missed during a copy/paste from elsewhere. I’ve updated it to try to make it more clear. Sorry about that!

Comment: There's no code in libgit2 or LibGit2Sharp to escalate privileges or otherwise run as Administrator, so this is an interesting question as to how the escalation is happening.

Comment: Maybe try right clicking on the shortcut, choosing advanced, and making sure the "Run as Administrator", button is not checked?

Comment: I looked at that, and it isn’t checked, but thanks.